LCNAF plugin archivesspace
I have to integrate LCNAF plugin in a website.
For the purpose I a configured the appconfig file and included the 'lcnaf' term. Additionally, in the plugins folder I have included the lcnaf files that I found on the github repo.
However, I am not able to see how that plugin is displayed or work. Can any one help me with the same. I am completely new to Archivesspace and lcnaf.
I just need to see how that plugin works in actions and what other settings I need to do.
I just need to see how that plugin works in actions and what other settings I need to do.

I think this covers everything you would need to know? https://archivesspace.github.io/tech-docs/customization/plugins.html

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
